# Simplifying polynomials to a variable power

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function, exponentiation

The context of this question is this:

For something like the equation
$$ax^n + bx + c = 0$$

Is it possible to solve for the roots?

More specifically for the following equation:

$$(1+r)^n + cr - 1 = 0$$

Is it possible to solve for r in terms of c and n? How?

Comment: If you substitute $x=1+r$, then your second equation becomes $x^n+cx-(1+c)=0$ which is a special case of the former. However, the usual answer is _no_: If $n>4$, then there are polynomials of the form $x^n+bx+c=0$ such that its roots cannot be  expressed using radicals (like one can for quadratics). That doesn't stop you from making sensible approximations, though, and it's common to handle such problems in this way.

Comment: Is $r$ supposed to be  $\ll 1$ ? This looks like a finance problem. If it is, we could make quite good approximations.